# How to override div by id?

Tags: html, css, height

I want to edit my div with id but somewhere it won't load because its already defined and I can not override it. Maybe you guys have idea what is going on here.

Here is the problem
I want to edit this div but  height is already defined and seems like it won't override..
what can be the problem?
https://gyazo.com/03c4e641ba55863f82177a37214d7516

```css
div#main_slider{
  height: 471px;
  visible: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_slider" class="rev_slider fullscreenbanner" data-version="5.1.1RC">
</div>
```

Comment: Share your HTML as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a simple `div` you can use `!important` to override.

Beware of using `important` it should be used only as an last option because `important` overrides all property which you define.

> ```
> !important : ignore subsequent rules, and any usual specificity issues, apply this rule!'
> ```

```css
div#main_slider{
height: 471px !important;
visible: hidden;
border:1px solid black;
font-size: 24px !important;
 }
```

```html
<div id="main_slider" > My Div </div>
```

Here is the another solution without using `important` choose only the `id` selector.

```css
#main_slider{
   height: 471px;
   border:1px solid black;
   font-size: 24px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="main_slider" class="rev_slider fullscreenbanner" data-version="5.1.1RC">My Div
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly with important.. why we  must use important.. thank you so much!!

Comment: Kindly accept and vote if you think if it is worth. I have mentioned importance of `important` as well.

Comment: @vol7ron, I added that code to override the property, I have added another snippet which can be used without `important` thanks.

Comment: @Manjuboyz your new code wouldn't solve his problem.  Upon further review, your initial solution is one of two options that would work; however, you should encourage finding the other solution or warn about the implications of using `!important`.  I removed my downvote, but I think you should also remove that last solution

Comment: I have updated but I would like to keep the last snippet which uses only `id` selector.

Comment: @Manjuboyz I've posted an answer to demonstrate to you why your last example won't work.  Refer to the first example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60755747/183181. ID selector won't overwrite inline styling (styling directly applied to the element or through the DOM).

Answer (score 2):

As you said the `id` is already defined, you have the following options to resolve this -

- Use `!important`
- Use inline styling for the specific `div`
- Provide div another `id` & use this new `id` to override.

Comment: Thank you. !important fixed issues. Finally have all working!

Answer (score 0):

## Inline Style

The link you posted to demonstrated a DIV that has inline styling.  This is different from styling already being applied via other CSS styling and cannot be overwritten by ordinary styling rules

Example

```css
#main_slider{
  height: 100vh;
  background: red; /* <-- won't override the inline style */
}
```

```html
<div id="main_slider" 
  class="rev_slider fullscreenbanner" 
  data-version="5.1.1RC"
  style="background: yellow;">
</div>
```

---

## Override Inline Styling

You have two options to apply styling to elements that have inline styling.

### 1. More Inline Styling

This can be accomplished in one of two ways; directly on the element or via a script. In the example a yellow background is applied directly to the element. More than likely, if you didn't add the inline style in the first place, it was updated dynamically via a script. You can use a script to also update it as demonstrated in the example below.

Example

```js
main_slider.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

```css
#main_slider{
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_slider" 
  class="rev_slider fullscreenbanner" 
  data-version="5.1.1RC"
  style="background: yellow;">
</div>
```

Notice the only difference was moving the CSS to JavaScript. In this case, the `red` overwrote the previously existing `yellow`.

### 2. Use `!important`

The `!important` flag gives it precedence over inline styling and specificity of non-!important styling; however, this method should be used as a last resort.  The only way to later override the `!important` is with more of them (in addition to specificity).

```css
#main_slider{
  height: 100vh;
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_slider" 
  class="rev_slider fullscreenbanner" 
  data-version="5.1.1RC"
  style="background: yellow;">
</div>
```